# how to solve this integral $2\pi\int_1^a {1\over x} {\sqrt {1+{1\over x^4}}} dx $

Tags: calculus

Can you help me to solve this integral?

$$2\pi\int_1^a {1\over x} {\sqrt {1+{1\over x^4}}} dx $$

Comment: Because you do not indicate any attempt on your own part to solve this, it appears that the valid Answers proposed by some Readers are not at the level you need or expect.  In the future be more explicit about where you got stuck on such exercises so that help can be better targeted.

Comment: @hardmath You are a genius thanks for your help

Comment: Techniques of integration are tough material to get through, no doubt.  Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would first get rid of the high negative powers of $x$, so $\frac1{x^2}=u$
$$\int\frac1x\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^4}}dx=-\frac12\int\frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}udu$$
Then the best hyperbolic substitution looks like $u=\text{csch}\theta$, so
$$\begin{align}\int\frac1x\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^4}}dx&=\frac12\int\coth^2\theta\,d\theta=\frac12\int\left(1+\text{csch}^2\theta\right)d\theta\\
&=\frac12(\theta-\coth\theta)+C=\frac12\left(\text{csch}^{-1}u-\sqrt{1+u^2}\right)+C \\
&=\frac12\left(\ln\left(\frac1u+\sqrt{\frac1{u^2}+1}\right)-\sqrt{1+u^2}\right)+C\\
&=\frac12\left(\ln\left(x^2+\sqrt{1+x^4}\right)-\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^4}}\right)+C\end{align}$$
So we get to
$$2\pi\int_1^a\frac1x\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^4}}dx=\pi\left(\ln\left(a^2+\sqrt{1+a^4}\right)-\sqrt{1+\frac1{a^4}}-\ln\left(1+\sqrt2\right)+\sqrt2\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: change of variables $u = \sqrt{1 + 1/x^4}$.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the integral as $\displaystyle 2\pi\int_1^a\frac{\sqrt{x^4+1}}{x^3}dx=\pi\int_1^a\frac{\sqrt{x^4+1}}{x^4}\;2x dx;\;\;$

now let $u=x^2$ to get $\displaystyle \pi\int_1^{a^2}\frac{\sqrt{u^2+1}}{u^2}du$, and then let $u=\tan\theta, du=\sec^2\theta d\theta$ to get

$\displaystyle\pi\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\tan^{-1}a^2}\frac{\sec\theta}{\tan^2\theta}\;\sec^2\theta d\theta=\pi\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\tan^{-1}a^2}\frac{\sec\theta}{\tan^2\theta}\;(\tan^2\theta+1) d\theta=\pi\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\tan^{-1}a^2}(\sec\theta+\csc\theta\cot\theta) d\theta$

$\displaystyle=\pi\big[\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)-\csc\theta\big]_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\tan^{-1}a^2}=\pi\left(\ln(\sqrt{a^4+1}+a^2)-\frac{\sqrt{a^4+1}}{a^2}-\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)+\sqrt{2}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

You can first compute the [indefinite integral](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B1%20%7D%7Bx%7D%20%5Csqrt%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E%7B4%7D%7D%20%7D/?origin=button):

$$\frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\mathrm{arctanh}\Bigg(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^4}+1}\Bigg) - \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^4}+1} \Bigg) + C$$

Then you can easily put in your limits.